# Daily update on PHP logic

Tags: php, cron

There is a case that if the employee that already worked for a year since the join_date, he will be given 12 leave_balance, but how to determine for the next year ? Because it can't be multiplied by difference in year. For example

- join_date 15 Jan 2015, today date is 15 Jan 2016, then update leave_balance = leave_balance + 12;
- but then, between 15 Jan 2016 - 15 Jan 2017 he use his vacation for 5 days, so his leave_balance will be 8,
- on 15 Jan 2017, he will receive another leave balance quota 12, so leave_balance must update 8 + 12 = 20.

what I have thought is only like this 
if(join_date  = same date this year)
then update leave_balance

please help

table needed is very simple, status_employee,join_date and leave_balance

```
$q = "select * from employee";
$r = mysql-query($q);
while($result = mysql_fetch_array($r))
{
    $datetime1 = new DateTime($result['join_date']);
    $interval = $datetime1->diff(new DateTime());
    $year= $interval->y;

       if($year > 0 && status_employee = 'Permanent Staff')
       {
             $leave_balance = $result['leave_balance'] + (12 * $year);
       }
}
```

for ilustration

**UPDATE**
[image]

```
$q = "SELECT * FROM employee WHERE employee_type = 'Permanent' && DATEDIFF(.join_date , CURDATE()) >= 365";

$r = mysql_query($q);
while($res = mysql_fetch_array($r))
{
    $q = "SELECT * FROM holiday_transaction WHERE id_employee='".$res['id_employee']."'";
    $r = mysql_query($r);
    $res = mysql_fetch_array($r);
    $check = mysql_num_rows($r);

$id_employee = $res['id_employee'];
if($check > 0) //employee is on the transaction_table
{
    //check latest renewal date
    $q = "SELECT * FROM holiday_transaction WHERE id_employee = '$id_employee' && transaction_type='Renewal' && DATEDIFF(CURDATE() ,trn_date) >= 365";
    $r = mysql_query($q);
    $check = mysql_num_rows($r);

    if($check == 0) //0 means he qualify with conditions above that his latest renewal is already more than a year
    {
        $q = "INSERT INTO holiday_transaction(id_employee,holiday,transaction_type) VALUES('$id_employee','12','Renewal')";
        mysql_query($q)
    }
    else
    {
        //don't insert because it is not yet 365days since his latest renewal
    }

}
else //never been on the table and give 12 quota
{
    $q = "INSERT INTO holiday_transaction(id_employee,holiday,transaction_type) VALUES('$id_employee','12','Renewal')"; 
    mysql_query($q)
}
```

}

Answer (score 3):

You do not need a cron job.  You can just run a stored procedure on mysql or just some php code when someone next logs on.  JUst do it before presenting them with a page.

Comment: And what about the algorithm to check to update the balance ?

Comment: Oh you want everything.  Actually you already have the algorithm above.  What you want is the coding.  **1)**  You shouldn't ask multiple questions in one post.   **2)**  You have to share your table metadata.  **3)**  You have to show us what you have tried.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your second question. If I was doing it I would have a transaction table.  This would ensure that even if the code ran twice it would not double things up.  It also gives you an exact trace in case of disputes by employees.  Like this:

```
table employee_holidays
employee_ref (index into employee table)
trn_date (the date that these holidays were added or taken)
holidays (integer)
```

Then

1. You apply your annual holidays of 12 any time after the end of the year and use the year-end as the date.  If the entry is already there for that date then you don't add it.
2. Every time an employee takes a holiday, you add a negative entry for that date.
3. To find out how many holidays they have left, you sum them up.

If you really want a ready total then I would have a totals table (or use the employee_table.leave_balance).  **BUT** I would use a trigger in the transaction table to update this figure.

I think that once you have this together and can't get something working then you should ask a new question.

Comment: well it's not the end of the year, it's year later since the join_date, what I was worried is, how to update when it's the same time with his join_date. Or should I make it like this ?

so if (trn_type = renewal && date_trn is not between date_trn - date_trn+1year)
then it's okay to add ? is it something like that ?
here's a link to that http://imgur.com/NM9EmlW